# C++ error C2665: none of the 2 overloads could convert all the arg types

Tags: c++, overloading

in `file.hpp` I got

```
void func(std::vector<double>& vec, const std::pair<const A, const B>& map,
          const C& swap, const V* v, const D& date1, const D& date2, const int dim);
```

in `file2.cpp`

```
void func2(std::vector<double>& vec, const A& p1, const B& p2,
          const C& swap, const V* v, const D& date1, const D& date2, const int dim) {
    func(vec, make_pair(p1, p2), swap, v , date1, date2, dim);
}
```

The error lies in the line `func(vec, std::make_pair<p1, p2>, swap, v, date1, date2, dim)`

it says: **none of the two overloads could convert all the arguments types** (I have overloaded the `func` function)

Comment: Seems like you make `std::pair<const A&, const B&>`, no?

Comment: Your code block and following line are inconsistent: did you have `std::make_pair<p1,p2>` or `make_pair(p1, p2)`? Both are wrong, but the former gives the error reported. Should be a hybrid of the two: `std::make_pair(p1, p2)`.

Comment: in my code it is `std::make_pair(p1, p2)` sorry

Comment: Then ... not reproducible. I gave some dummy definitions for your `A, B, C, D, V` types and the code compiles.

Comment: But, as @AlexeyLarionov says, maybe its the references to `A` and `B` that are the problem - difficult to say, without knowing how those types are defined.